# SQL Server group by set of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have a table with data that look like this:

```
   product_id | filter_id
     __________________
        4525    5066
        4525    5068
        4525    5091
        4526    5066
        4526    5068
        4526    5094
        4527    5066
        4527    5068
        4527    5094
        4528    5066
        4528    5071
        4528    5078
```

which is actualy groups of three filters for each product e.g. product 4525 has the filters 5066,5068 and 5091.

The second and third group, is the exact same set of filters (5066,5068 and 5094) bound to a different product ( 4526 and 4527 ).

I want to have each unique filter set only one time ( in other words, I want to remove the duplicate sets of filter_ids ). I don't really care what will happen to the product_id, I only want my unique sets of three filter_ids to be grouped with a key.

For example this will also do:

```
   new_id | filter_id
   __________________
        1   5066
        1   5068
        1   5091
        2   5066
        2   5068
        2   5094
        3   5066
        3   5071
        3   5078
```

I hope I explained it well enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Can u check the query below ...

Comment: In the test case you have 4 different product id, is the expected result correct or should there be another group of filter with new_id 4?

Comment: @Serpiton On my case, it won't be more than 3 because that's the number of filters I use. But It could be more yes. I also noticed that groups of less filters may appear.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query, which is a bit longer than I expected. Not getting any other logic as of now !!!

```
select 
    distinct filter_id, 
    DENSE_RANK() over(order by sc) new_id
from(
    select *,
        (SELECT ' ' + cast(filter_id as nvarchar(10))
           FROM tbl b where b.product_id=a.product_id order by filter_id
            FOR XML PATH('')) SC
    From tbl a
)x
order by new_id
```

/*-------------- Other Way ------------------*/

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) new_id, 
    filter_id 
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE product_id in (
    SELECT MIN(product_id) FROM(
        SELECT 
            product_id,
            SUM(filter_id*RN) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID) SM
        FROM(
            SELECT 
                *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY filter_id) RN
            FROM Table1
        )x
    )xx GROUP BY SM)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I have to take a closer loot at the results to be sure... Thank you.

Comment: This works just fine! Thanks! The approach is really cool and I came up with something similar which might be slightly faster. I just have to run some more tests.

Comment: this is funny because this is almost like my approach. I suppose that making a unique number via multiplication or power, is faster than concatenation ( I haven't tested it yet ). But I'm not so sure if the numbers will be unique and will never exceed the `bigint`. I have to do a little more research but unfortunately not now because I am at work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dense_rank() 
over(order by product_id asc),filter_id
from table
```

Comment: It does not produce the desired result, even if I change the columns, it also has a syntax error (the first `asc`) but that doesn't matter...

Comment: i am sorry remove partition and try

Comment: It just replaces the product_ids with new id's, as a result I have the same result set I used to do, no duplicates removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the question the expected result only have the filter_id of the product 4525, 4526 and 4528 because 4526 and 4527 have the same filter_id, so only one of those is needed, in that case this query will do:

```
SELECT product_id
     , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) new_id
     , filter_id
FROM   table1 c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table1 a
                          LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.product_id < b.product_id
                   WHERE  b.product_id = c.product_id
                   GROUP BY a.product_id, b.product_id
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.filter_id)
                        = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.filter_id = b.filter_id THEN 1 
                                     ELSE NULL 
                                END));
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f5f2/42)</kbd>

To get the result the first step is to remove the products with a full duplicate list of filter_ID. To get those product the subquery check every product couple to see if the number of filter_id in one is equal to the filter_id shared by the couple.

If you can have product with different number of filters and if a product with a list of filter fully contained in the filter list of another product should be removed from the result, for example if with the base data

```
product_id | filter_id
-----------+----------
      4525 |      5066
      4525 |      5068
      4525 |      5091
      4526 |      5066
      4526 |      5068
```

the expected result is

```
new_id | filter_id
-------+----------
     1 |      5066
     1 |      5068
     1 |      5091
```

the query need to be changed to

```
SELECT product_id
     , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) new_id
     , filter_id
FROM   table1 c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.product_id
                   FROM   table1 a
                          LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.product_id < b.product_id
                   WHERE b.product_id IS NOT NULL
                     AND b.product_id = c.product_id
                   GROUP BY a.product_id, b.product_id
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.filter_id)
                        = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.filter_id = b.filter_id THEN 1 
                                     ELSE NULL 
                                END)
                       OR COUNT(DISTINCT b.filter_id)
                        = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.filter_id = b.filter_id THEN 1 
                                     ELSE NULL 
                                END));
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f5f2/43)</kbd>

---

I came out with a query quite similar to the second one of TechDo, nine hour after after him. Even if the result is similar, as the idea is different, my idea is to concat the values of filter_id with math

```
;WITH B AS (
  SELECT Product_ID
       , filter_id = filter_id - MIN(filter_id) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)
       , _ID = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID ORDER BY filter_id) - 1
       , N = CEILING(LOG10(MAX(filter_id) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)
                         - MIN(filter_id) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)))
  FROM   table1 a
), G1 AS (
  SELECT Product_ID
       , _ID = SUM(Filter_ID * POWER(10, N * _ID))
  FROM   B
  GROUP BY Product_ID
), G2 AS (
  SELECT Product_ID = MIN(Product_ID)
  FROM   G1
  GROUP BY _ID
)
SELECT g2.product_id
     , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY g2.PRODUCT_ID) new_id
     , a.filter_id
FROM   G2
       INNER JOIN table1 a ON g2.product_id = a.product_id;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f5f2/39)</kbd>

The first `CTE` do a lot of work:

- `filter_id` is reduced in rank (the reduction from 0 to n-1 digits, depending on the range of the data)
- is generated a order number for the filter within the product (`_ID`)
- is calculated the max number of digits of the reduced filter_id (`N`)

In the following `CTE` those values are used to generate the filter concatenation using the `SUM`, the formula `SUM(Filter_ID * POWER(10, N * _ID))` put a reduced filter_id every N position, for example with the data provided by the OP we have that the max difference of filter_id is 28, so N is 2 and the results are (the points are added for readability)

```
Product_ID  _ID
----------- -----------
4525        25.02.00
4526        28.02.00
4527        28.02.00
4528        12.05.00
```

The formula used make collision between different filter group impossible, but need a larger space to be calculated, if the range of the filter_id is big it can hit the limit if the integer.

Comment: This works just fine but it gets really slow when the table has more than 100 rows, with my server at least. It did approx 150ms for 100rows and went up to 1.5s for 200 rows. Nice approach though.

Comment: It does give a better performance, although I didn't expect to but still not good enough, dropped to 400ms for 200 rows but 3s for 300 rows... @TechDo's approach does 50ms for 300 rows.

Comment: I don't like the string manipulation either so I tried a slightly different approach which seems as fast. I have to do some research about it though. And I'm at work too so it's 'maybe later' for me too.